# str_extract specific patterns (example)

Tags: regex, r

I'm still a little confused by regex syntax. Can you please help me with these patterns:

```
_A00_A1234B_
_A00_A12345B_
_A1_A12345_
```

my approaches so far:

```
vapply(strsplit(files, "[_.]"), function(files) files[nchar(files) == 7][1], character(1))
```

or

```
str_extract(str2, "[A-Z][0-9]{5}[A-Z]")
```

The expected outputs are

```
A1234B
A12345B
A12345
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @rkay the `str_extract` code gets you the 2nd element ie. `A12345B` ie. `capital letter` `[A-Z]` followed by `5 digits` ie. `[0-9]{5}` followed by capital letter `[A-Z]`. The first and third elements are returned NA because they don't have the pattern as described.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the expected output. The problem is that the number of digits varies, i.e. 4-5 digits, sometimes the subsequent char is missing.

Comment: Okay, got it : str_extract(files, "[A-Z][0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str2, "[A-Z][0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]?")
#[1] "A1234B"  "A12345B" "A12345"
```

Here, the pattern looks for a capital letter `[A-Z]`, followed by `4` or 5 digits `[0-9]{4,5}`, followed by a capital letter `[A-Z]`  `?`

Or you can use `stringi` which would be faster

```
library(stringi)
 stri_extract(str2, regex="[A-Z][0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]?")
 #[1] "A1234B"  "A12345B" "A12345"
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
 regmatches(str2,regexpr('[A-Z][0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]?', str2))
 #[1] "A1234B"  "A12345B" "A12345"
```

#### data

```
str2 <- c('_A00_A1234B_', '_A00_A12345B_', '_A1_A12345_')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vec <- c("_A00_A1234B_", "_A00_A12345B_", "_A1_A12345_")
```

You can use `sub` and this regex:

```
sub(".*([A-Z]\\d{4,5}[A-Z]?).*", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "A1234B"  "A12345B" "A12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) to construct the regular expression may make it more understandable.

```
x <- c("_A00_A1234B_", "_A00_A12345B_", "_A1_A12345_")

# approach #1, assumes always is between the second underscores.
re_matches(x,
  rex(
    "_",
    anything,
    "_",
    capture(anything),
    "_"
  )
)

#>         1
#> 1  A1234B
#> 2 A12345B
#> 3  A12345


# approach #2, assumes an alpha, followed by 4 or 5 digits with a possible trailing alpha.
re_matches(x,
  rex(
    capture(
      alpha,
      between(digit, 4, 5),
      maybe(alpha)
    )
  )
)

#>         1
#> 1  A1234B
#> 2 A12345B
#> 3  A12345
```

Comment: I could be wrong as I never used the `rex` before. So, thanks for introducing it.  But based on the syntax you showed, the `capture(anything)` comes after the 2nd `_`.  What if one of the element is `_A1234B_A00_`?

Comment: The question wasn't clear about how the needed elements were identified, I assumed from the first example he gave that they were always the second part.  Doing your regex in `rex` would be `rex(capture(alpha, between(digit, 4, 5), maybe(alpha)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using a regular expression ...

```
x <- c('_A00_A1234B_', '_A00_A12345B_', '_A1_A12345_')
sapply(strsplit(x, '_', fixed=T), '[', 3)
# [1] "A1234B"  "A12345B" "A12345"
```

If you insist on using a regular expression, the following will suffice.

```
regmatches(x, regexpr('[^_]+(?=_$)', x, perl=T))
```

Comment: Never thought I will ever hear you saying something like `You can do this without using a regular expression`...