# How to do str_extract with base R?

Tags: r, regex

I am balancing several versions of R and want to change my R libraries loaded depending on which R and which operating system I'm using. As such, I want to stick with base R functions.

I was reading this page to see what the base R equivalent to `stringr::str_extract` was:

http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html

It suggested I could replicate this functionality with `grep`. However, I haven't been able to get `grep` to do more than return the whole string if there is a match. Is this possible with `grep` alone, or do I need to combine it with another function? In my case I'm trying to distinguish between CentOS versions 6 and 7.

```
grep(pattern = "release ([0-9]+)", x = readLines("/etc/system-release"), value = TRUE)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27274231/1017276

Comment: I think this is a good specific question that should have an answer (rather than closing as a dupe, unless a more exact match can be found). But please make a nice example that doesn't rely on OS-specific files to reproduce. Maybe even borrow some of the examples in `?str_extract`.

Comment: The right answer is: each regex should be adjusted for use with base R regex functions. There is no universal solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**1) strcapture** If you want to extract a string of digits and dots from `"release 1.2.3"` using base then

```
x <- "release 1.2.3"
strcapture("([0-9.]+)", x, data.frame(version = character(0)))
##   version
## 1   1.2.3
```

**2) regexec/regmatches** There is also `regmatches` and `regexec` but that has already been covered in another answer.

**3) sub** Also it is often possible to use `sub`:

```
sub(".* ([0-9.]+).*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**3a)** If you know the match is at the beginning or end then delete everything after  or before it:

```
sub(".* ", "", x)
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**4) gsub** Sometimes we know that the field to be extracted has certain characters and they do not appear elsewhere.  In that case simply delete every occurrence of every character that cannot be in the string:

```
gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x)
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**5) read.table** One can often decompose the input into fields and then pick off the desired one by number or via `grep`.  `strsplit`, `read.table` or `scan` can be used:

```
read.table(text = x, as.is = TRUE)[[2]]
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**5a) grep/scan**

```
grep("^[0-9.]+$", scan(textConnection(x), what = "", quiet = TRUE), value = TRUE)
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**5b) grep/strsplit**

```
grep("^[0-9.]+$", strsplit(x, " ")[[1]], value = TRUE)
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**6) substring** If we know the character position of the field we can use `substring` like this:

```
substring(x, 9)
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**6a) substring/regexpr** or we may be able to use `regexpr` to locate the character position for us:

```
substring(x, regexpr("\\d", x))
## [1] "1.2.3"
```

**7) read.dcf** Sometimes it is possible to convert the input to dcf form in which case it can be read with `read.dcf`.  Such data is of the form `name: value`

```
 read.dcf(textConnection(sub(" ", ": ", x)))
 ##      release
 ## [1,] "1.2.3"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
txt <- c("foo release 123", "bar release", "foo release 123 bar release 123")
pattern <- "release ([0-9]+)"
stringr::str_extract(txt, pattern)
# [1] "release 123" NA            "release 123"
sapply(regmatches(txt, regexec(pattern, txt)), "[", 1)
# [1] "release 123" NA            "release 123"
```

Comment: Note that with`regexec` it is not possible to use PCRE patterns. `stringr` regex is based on ICU and supports look arounds while base R TRE default regex engine does not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point. However, setting the `perl` argument to `TRUE`, one can also use perl-compatible regular expressions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew According to the documentation `regexec` supports `perl = TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

```
txt <- c("foo release 123", "bar release", "foo release 123 bar release 123")
pattern <- "release ([0-9]+)"
```

**Extract first match**

```
sapply(
    X = txt,
    FUN = function(x){
        tmp = regexpr(pattern, x)
        m = attr(tmp, "match.length")
        st = unlist(tmp)
        if (st == -1){NA}else{substr(x, start = st, stop = st + m - 1)}
    },
    USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "release 123" NA            "release 123"
```

**Extract all matches**

```
sapply(
    X = txt,
    FUN = function(x){
        tmp = gregexpr(pattern, x)
        m = attr(tmp[[1]], "match.length")
        st = unlist(tmp)
        if (st[1] == -1){
            NA
        }else{
                sapply(seq_along(st), function(i) substr(x, st[i], st[i] + m[i] - 1))
            }
    },
    USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "release 123"

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] "release 123" "release 123"
```