# Base R Equivalent of `stringr::str_extract_all`

Tags: r, regex, string

How could one implement the `str_extract_all` function from the {stringr} package in base R? I found a way to implement `str_extract` based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678871/4398177):

```r
str_extract <- function(string, pattern) {
  regmatches(string, regexpr(pattern, string))
}
```

However, this returns only the *first* matching pattern in `string`, e.g.

```r
pattern <- "xx|xx\\."
str_extract("xx (xx.)", pattern)
```

```
[1] "xx"
```

Whereas `stringr::str_extract_all` would return

```
[1] "xx" "xx."
```

which is what I'm after.

Comment: Use gregexpr instead of regexpr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `regexpr()` for `gregexpr()` will do the trick:

```
str_extract <- function(string, pattern) {
  regmatches(string, gregexpr(pattern, string))
}

pattern <- "xx|xx\\."
str_extract("xx (xx.)", pattern)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "xx"  "xx."
```

R's documentation is quite straightforward about the functions **regexpr** and **gregexpr**:

> regexpr returns an integer vector of the same length as text giving
> the starting position of the first match or -1 if there is none, with
> attribute "match.length", an integer vector giving the length of the
> matched text (or -1 for no match).

and

> gregexpr returns a list of the same length as text each element of
> which is of the same form as the return value for regexpr, except that
> the starting positions of every (disjoint) match are given.