# R - Reg Ex to match everything after a fixed pattern incl space and punctuation

Tags: r

This is not a repeat question, please do not flag. I've searched online here and elsewhere, found similar questions, but none of them answer apply to my question. These come up but do not answer the question I have:

[How to extract everything after a specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204659/)

[stringr str_extract capture group capturing everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787725/)

[str_extract specific patterns (example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273996/)

I need to extract everything in a string that comes after specific patterns of characters, not a set/s of characters. The solution is probably simple, I can't figure it out.

EG data are below with the initial text and what I'd like the result to look like. I need a Reg Ex that would capture everything that comes after ": - ". I've gotten close, but have been unable to get the Reg Ex to ignore the second instance of a dash in Text value1, and the apostrophe in Text value2. It's probably easy, sorry, thank you in advance.

```
tibble(
 Text = c(
"Please advise: - How to extract this part.",
"Please advise: - I'm not sure how to extract the latter part of this, and I really need to.", 
"Please advise: - My co-workers can't help me."),
 IdealOutcome = c(
"How to extract this part.",
"I'm not sure how to extract the latter part of this, and I really need to.",
"My co-workers can't help me.")) -> eg_data
```

Comment: `sapply(str_split(eg_data$Text, ': - '), \`[\`, 2)` ?

Comment: The 'text, I'm no good.', if changed to "text, I'm no good" relieves one problem, the scope of the text is between matching quotes, interior ones have to be different. Thereafter, you can unlist(strsplit(Text[1], split = '- '))[2], but the order of quote marks needs to be addressed. If your data is problematic, look at [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77456292/import-csv-with-case-invariant-na-strings-argument), for an approach.

Comment: Axeman's works, but can someone help me with a RegEx for this? Specifically, I was close but was unable to get my RegEx to work for the third pattern in my example, it kept extracting 'My co' IE cutting off at the dash in the part of the text after the specific pattern. I was unable to put within the RegEx that pattern such that it'd look for those characters in that order as opposed to any of those characters. Thank you for the help, Axeman.

Comment: Text3 = c("Please advise: - My co-workers can't help me.") `strsplit(Text3, split = '- ')[[1]][2]
[1] "My co-workers can't help me."`

Answer (score 0):

May this would help to extract what you want:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(Text, pattern = "(?<=(: - ))(.)*")
```